# Creating a directional air burst dash mechanic for a 3D game

Tags: game-physics, game-development, godot, gdscript

My issue is the dash is not dashing. I'm new to Godot and I wrote all of this in a day, and the last thing I need for basic movement mechanics is this dash.

Movement code:

```
extends CharacterBody3D
#variables to be exported and displayed on the player game object
@export var player_speed = 12.0

@export var fall_acceleration = 60

@export var jump_height = 100

@export var jump_velocity = 20

@export var dash_velocity = 20

@onready var jumpcd_time = $JumpCd_Timer

@onready var dash_time = $DashTimer

var target_velocity = Vector3.ZERO



var jumpCD_On = false

var jump_amount = 0

var can_jumpDash = false



func jump():
    # Edit the argument to how many seconds you want the times to be
    jumpcd_time.set_wait_time(3)#seconds
    
    # Setting one_shot to true so the timers can stop when it hits 0
    jumpcd_time.one_shot = true
    
    if jumpcd_time.time_left == 0:
        jumpCD_On = false
        
    if  is_on_floor() and jumpCD_On == false and Input.is_action_just_pressed("jump"):
        can_jumpDash = true
        target_velocity.y = jump_velocity

        jumpcd_time.start()
        jumpCD_On = true

    elif not is_on_floor() and can_jumpDash == true and Input.is_action_just_pressed("jump"):
        double_jump_air_dash()
            
        can_jumpDash = false
        
    if jumpcd_time.is_stopped() == true:
        jumpCD_On = false
        

func double_jump_air_dash():
    if Input.is_action_pressed("move_forward"):
        print("forward dash")
            
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("move_backword"):
        print("backword dash")
            
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("move_left"):
        print("left dash")
            
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("move_right"):
        print("right dash")
        # TODO: Get the movement for dash
    else:
        target_velocity.y = jump_velocity
        print("double jump")
        
func normalize_speed(direction):
    if direction != Vector3.ZERO:
        direction = direction.normalized()
        """Basis is the transfom matrix (x xy xz xw)
                                        (xy y yz yw)
                                        (xz yz z zw)
                                        (xw yw zw w)"""
        $PlayerDirection.basis = Basis.looking_at(direction)


func _physics_process(delta):
    var direction = Vector3.ZERO
    
    # Gather user input detection
    if Input.is_action_pressed("move_forward"):
        direction.x += 1
        
    if Input.is_action_pressed("move_backword"):
        direction.x -= 1

    if Input.is_action_pressed("move_left"):
        direction.z -= 1

    if Input.is_action_pressed("move_right"):
        direction.z += 1
        
    jump()
    normalize_speed(direction)
    
    
    # Ground velocity for directional movement + jump movement
    target_velocity.x = direction.x * player_speed
    target_velocity.z = direction.z * player_speed
    
    if not is_on_floor():
        target_velocity.y = target_velocity.y - (fall_acceleration * delta)
    
    velocity = target_velocity
    move_and_slide()
```

I tried implementing a similar thing with the double jump which either didn't work logically or didn't work because I messed up with something.

Comment: I am reading into state machines so might be the answer there

Comment: So you are saying the `print`s in `double_jump_air_dash` do not show up? *Btw, the `Basis` is 9 numbers, not 16.*

Comment: The prints show up just cannot get the actual velocity to take effect when I apply velocity changes.

Comment: You are away you only modify `target_velocity` in one of the cases, is the print from that particular case showing up?